# jQuery Flyin effect not center

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make a jquery effect center on my page but instead its off to the right by about 150px. Is there another way of keeping this effect but ensuring the div is central.

```
$(window).load(function() {
var currWidth = $(window).width();
console.log(currWidth);

var startPos = -100;
var endPos = (currWidth / 2) + (startPos / 2);
console.log(endPos);
$('#welcome').animate({left: endPos}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS too? A jsFiddle.net example would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function() {
var currWidth = $(window).width();

var element = 270; //half the size of the element
var put = (currWidth / 2) - element; //work out the margin left to put the element

$('#welcome').animate({left: put}, 1000);
});
```